# how can i access the value of the object in which the key is comming from the value of another object as shown in the below code

Tags: html, angularjs, web

First object item
'''

```
{
$$hashKey: "object:124"
$metadata: {editMode: false}
account: {accountID: 0, accountType: {…}, status: {…}, kycStatus: {…}, balance: 100, …}
accountID: 0
property: "account.agent.instanceID"
value: "1"
}
```

'''
and another object is accountInputType
'''

```
{
account.agent.instanceID: "text"
account.agent.softphoneAllocationMethod: "text"
account.agentlogin.resetSoftphoneServer: "options"
account.balance.allowNegBalance: "options"
account.balance.threshold: "text"
account.calling.allowInternational: "options"
account.customreport.displayFromLastX.daily: "text"
account.customreport.displayFromLastX.hourly: "text"
account.customreport.displayFromLastX.monthly: "text"
account.customreport.displayFromLastX.weekly: "text"
account.did.maxDidsAllowed: "text"
account.flow.manualCall.flowID: "text"
account.flow.manualCall.securityID: "text"
account.login.allowSoftphone: "options"
account.validity.thresholdInDays: "text"
account.web.allowDashboardAnalytics: "options"
account.web.allowInsecureHttp: "options"
}
```

'''
I need to extract the text or options from the second object and the key to second object is item.property

Currently i am extracting as {{accountInputType[{{item.property}}]}} but this gives error.

Kindly suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{accountInputType[item.property]}}`